# How to convert varbinary data type back to ascii in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rtf, varbinary

I am trying to get RTF data out of a image date field in MS SQL.  Not so easy.

The issue is that when I do a straight binary dump of the data field it is not in RTF format.
Let me explain what is going on.  When I create a RTF file with Wordpad, and write that data to a varbinary(max), and reconvert it, the result is jiberish.

Code to put RTF data into MS SQL:

```
exec master..sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
exec master..sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
DECLARE @objStream INT
DECLARE @imageBinary VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @filePath VARCHAR(8000)

select @imageBinary=Report from Mytable WHERE EncounterID=7
select @filePath='c:\temp\report.rtf'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @objStream OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objStream, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'Write', NULL, @imageBinary
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'SaveToFile', NULL,@filePath, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @objStream
```

In binary, the first part of this file goes like this 
0x7B 5C 72 74 66 31 5C 61 6E 73 69 5C 61 6E 73 69)
(ascii {\rtf1\ansi\ansi )
However, the varbinary field looks like this:
0xB0 04 01 00 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00

And when i take that data out of the database (by using the reverse of the procedure above), it is not a recognizable RTF file.  So, somehow MS is converting it in a way i can't recognize.  If I can figure out how to convert it back to ascii text then I can continue with my application.

Comment: Is this code complete/correct?  This appears to only be writing out the @imageBinary you pulled from the row.  How are you getting it into the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me. I suspect the issue must be how you are saving the file to the database.

```
CREATE TABLE #BlobTest
(
blob varbinary(max) 
)

INSERT INTO
    #BlobTest (blob)
SELECT  BulkColumn FROM Openrowset( 
      Bulk 'C:\testing.rtf', 
      SINGLE_BLOB) AS blob

GO

exec master..sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
exec master..sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
DECLARE @objStream INT
DECLARE @imageBinary VARBINARY(MAX)
DECLARE @filePath VARCHAR(8000)

select @imageBinary=blob from #BlobTest
select @filePath='c:\report.rtf'
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @objStream OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objStream, 'Type', 1
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'Open'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'Write', NULL, @imageBinary
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'SaveToFile', NULL,@filePath, 2
EXEC sp_OAMethod @objStream, 'Close'
EXEC sp_OADestroy @objStream
```

Comment: This works fine for me.  The root cause was that the data was not in fact RTF.  Its some other strange/custom beast.  But this is exactly right for moving binary data into and out of the databse.

Comment: I get this error:  Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\dev\testing.rtf" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'Ole Automation Procedures' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.